# Can't install several development libraries

Tags: installation, 12.10, updates, ppa

I can't install several packages. Here's what happened. I installed Ubuntu 12.04, added `ppa:ricotz/testing` and then upgraded to 12.10. My system works fine, but `apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal` for example, doesn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.6.0-0ubuntu3.2) but 3.6.1-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
                Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.6.0-0ubuntu3.2) but 3.6.1-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libvte-2.90-dev : Depends: libcairo2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for gnome-terminal could not be satisfied.
exit 100
```

I **no longer have `ppa:ricotz/testing`**, it was disabled/removed when I upgraded, I think, but I still get a ton of errors.

Comment: What's happening here is that the ricotz PPA has more recent version of GNOME applications/libraries than the ones shipped with Ubuntu. You should either re-enable the PPA or use tools like `ppa-purge` to restore the distribution software.

Comment: But I think it is a Precise only PPA, should I really activate it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try cleaning up your packages and package list. Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The first command will update your package list, the second one will remove all packages that are no longer necessary and the third command will install all packages that are needed by other packages, but not yet installed.